# Processing values from a Thread Executing a yield return Function

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I am new to multi threading and I am trying make an enumerator in a way that I receive a value as it is ready, but that it continues to process in the background.

I want to be able to use the final class like this:

```
 while (await asyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync())
 {
       T result = asyncEnum.Current;
       //Do Something
 }
```

But I want it to continue getting the next result while I am doing stuff in the while loop.

**Comment:** It can't be processed in parallel since each result depends on the previous result.

I thought of maybe having a queue with the results and having a thread work on getting the results while returning the first result in the queue but I can't get this to work. This is my try, but I don't know what to do `MoveNext()`:

**I Updated The Code**

```
public class AsyncEnumerator<T>
{
    private object _sync = new object();

    private readonly Queue<T> _queue;
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> _enumerable;

    public AsyncEnumerator(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        _enumerable = enumerable;
        _queue = new Queue<T>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Start getting results when requested the firstTime
    /// </summary>
    private bool _startFlag;

    public async Task<bool> MoveNextAsync()
    {
        if (_finished)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!_startFlag)
        {
            _startFlag = true;
            SetResultsAsync();
        }
        if (_queue.Count > 0)
        {
            Current = _queue.Dequeue();
            return true;
        }
        //What here?
        return await Task.Run(()=> true);
    }

    private T _current;
    public T Current
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_sync)
            {
                return _current;
            }
        }
        private set { _current = value; }
    }

    private bool _finished;

    private async Task SetResultsAsync()
    {
        IEnumerator<T> enumerator = _enumerable.GetEnumerator();
        bool moveNext = await Task.Run(() => enumerator.MoveNext());
        while (moveNext)
        {
            _queue.Enqueue(enumerator.Current);
            moveNext = await Task.Run(() => enumerator.MoveNext());
        }
        _finished = true;
    }
}
```

Obviously if there is a better way to do this I would like to know, I am new to multi threading.

Comment: You should not use async void methods, that will most likely cause you problems. Make MoveNextAsync async and make SetResultsAsync return a Task. By the way, there is an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` and an `IAsyncEnumerator<T>`...

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Still doesn't help me with the `MoveNextAsync()`... 
I fixed the things in the code

Comment: SetResultsAsync is missing an await in MoveNextAsync. Besides that, if the Queue is empty, doesn't that mean that all items were processed already? You would `return false;` in that case

Comment: Use the right tool and the right pattern. It looks like what you need is the Producer/Consumer pattern, look up the BlockingCollection<>

Comment: _"I want it to continue getting the next result while I am doing stuff in the while loop"_ -- concurrent computation (i.e. "doing stuff") requires multiple threads. It also requires _not_ waiting. But `await` waits. If you want concurrent operations, why did you write non-concurrent code? I agree with the previous comment, probably all you want is a `Task.Run()` to feed data into a `BlockingCollection<T>` instance, and a loop on `GetConsumingEnumerable()` to retrieve that data and process it. But it's not clear at all what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I want it to continue getting the next result while I am doing stuff in the while loop.

A plain async enumerator is the wrong solution here. Enumerators are a "pull" technology; they only do things when the consuming code requests the next item.

Think about your problem in terms of a "producer" and a "consumer". If the producer only does work when the consumer requests it to, then you have an enumerator scenario. In your case, you want the producer to be independently producing items, so an enumerator is not going to fit properly.

One option is [reactive extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985(v=vs.103).aspx); an observable represents a sequence of values similar to an enumerator, except that observables are a "push" technology. So the producer will push values to the consumer, which reacts to the new values coming in (hence the name Reactive).

It sounds like Rx would be a great fit for you, but it does have a fairly high learning curve.

A simpler option may be to use a more traditional producer/consumer queue. Since you want to consume it asynchronously, you're going to want an async-compatible producer/consumer queue. [`BufferBlock<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414(v=vs.110).aspx) is [one solution](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/11/async-producerconsumer-queue-using.html), as is the [`AsyncProducerConsumerQueue<T>`](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/1.0.2/netstandard1.3/doc/Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncProducerConsumerQueue'1) from [my AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx).

In both cases, you'd kick off the producer and then consume:

```
var queue = new BufferBlock<T>();

// Kick off producer
var producer = Task.Run(() =>
{
  while (...)
  {
    T value = ...;
    queue.Post(value);
  }
  queue.Complete();
});

// Consumer code
while (await queue.OutputAvailableAsync())
{
  var value = await queue.ReceiveAsync();
  ...
}
```

Eventually, you will want to `await` that `producer` task, so that you can properly detect any exceptions from your producer code.

Comment: why do you `await` twice? isn't once enough?

Comment: Technically, yes, once `OutputAvailableAsync` returns `true`, then the next `ReceiveAsync` will complete synchronously, so you *could* use `Receive` instead. I just use `ReceiveAsync` for consistency.